# What's is the equivalent of to jQuery .one() in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

How can you created an event emitter that is only triggered once and self-destructs after that. An equivalent to jQuery's .one() function?

Comment: you can always easily make your own simple little wrapper that calls the orig function and then unbinds the wrapper from the event.

Comment: @dandavis not only that, it should wrap the whole binding call (so that it had the target and the event name)

Comment: @zerkms: i thought those details were provided by the event arguments, but if not, then yes, good point, you will need to know the details ahead of time.

Comment: @dandavis I actually expected to be corrected that all those are passed and recoverable :-) So it's more a question like "can we do that that easily" than a statement :-)

Comment: i've had to build lots of EEs, it's one of my favorite patterns. If an implementation provides even just the basic on/off, then you can define once/many/until/while convenience methods by building on top of on/off...

Comment: Nope...Everytime i use the angular events, they are triggered trice per every broadcast, running any code in it trice, that's why I require the .one() equivalent if any exits or a trick to do so.

Comment: It will help if you provide some relevant code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You actually have one() available to you in AngularJS via the jqLite library. jsLite is an abridged version of jQuery that is the minimum needed to power Angular.

https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/function/angular.element

```
var e = angular.element(document.querySelector('.myDivClass'));

    e.one('click', function(){
        alert("Only works once!");
    });
```

Example on [Codepen](http://codepen.io/cpk/pen/EaLggv)

Comment: If you are going to downvote, let me know why so I can update my answer.