# Is it possible to fire an event only once if any part of an Angular form element comes into focus?

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, angular-validation

I'm working with Angular forms and trying to see if there is a better way to fire an event on the first initial focus of any cell within a form. This way the event only gets called once.

I am aware you can fire an event by adding the attribute ng-focus to each of the cell elements. However, this will result in the event being fired every time each of the form's cell elements gains focus.

Lets say we have this form with inputs, text-areas, and radio buttons, etc.

***I was hoping that this would work but it does not:***

Adding the attribute **`ng-cell-has-focus="vm.clearAllMessages()"`** on the **`<form>`** element

```
<form
  name="vm.form"
  novalidate
  ng-cell-has-focus="vm.clearAllMessages()"
  ng-submit="vm.form.$valid && vm.sendForm($event)">
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="name-id">Name</label>
    <input id="name-id"
           name="name"
           type="text"
           ng-model="vm.formData.username"
           autofocus
           required>
    <div class="error-message"
         ng-messages="vm.form.name.$error"
         ng-if="vm.form.name.$touched || vm.form.$submitted">
      <div ng-message="required">Name is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="email-id">Email</label>
    <input id="email-id"
           name="email"
           type="email"
           ng-model="vm.formData.emailAddress"
           required>
    <div class="error-message"
         ng-messages="vm.form.email.$error"
         ng-if="vm.form.email.$touched || vm.form.$submitted">
      <span ng-message="required">Email address is required.</span>
      <span ng-message="email">Please enter a valid email address.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <input id="radio-1-id"
           name="radio"
           type="radio"
           value="First option"
           ng-model="vm.formData.radio"
           required>
    <label for="radio-1-id">First option</label>
    <input id="radio-2-id"
           name="radio"
           type="radio"
           value="Second option"
           ng-model="vm.formData.radio"
           required>
    <label for="radio-2-id">Second option</label>
    <div class="error-message"
         ng-messages="vm.form.radio.$error"
         ng-if="vm.form.radio.$touched || vm.form.$submitted">
      <span ng-message="required">Choose an option is required.</span>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="message-id">Message</label>
    <textarea id="message-id"
              name="message"
              cols="1"
              rows="4"
              ng-model="vm.formData.message"
              placeholder="Type in Message here ..."
              required></textarea>
    <div class="error-message"
         ng-messages="vm.form.message.$error"
         ng-if="vm.form.message.$touched || vm.form.$submitted">
      <div ng-message="required">Message is required.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="terms-id">Agree to Terms of Use</label>
    <input id="terms-id"
           name="terms"
           type="checkbox"
           ng-model="vm.formData.terms"
           required>
    <div class="error-message"
         ng-messages="vm.form.emailConfirm.$error"
         ng-if="vm.form.emailConfirm.$touched || vm.form.$submitted">
      <div ng-message="required">You must agree to Terms of Use.</div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <button type="submit">SUBMIT</button>
</form>
```

Comment: Just remove the handler after it's fired...if you want to use a directive then you might have to create your own. Or if this is a component you can add the event listener in JS, and have it remove itself the first time the event is handled.

Comment: Here's an example https://plnkr.co/edit/I8TTqXJqN4tsNmNrVQpU?p=preview

Comment: `ng-cell-has-focus` is not a core AngularJS directive. The `ng-` prefix is reserved for core AngularJS directives.

Comment: Old answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28664823/whats-is-the-equivalent-of-to-jquery-one-in-angularjs) , though angular may well have moved on since then.